# Reflection of HDRI in Cycles not working?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I added a HDRI as enviroment on cycles, but the model that i got here (an Eye) isnt reflecting good, at least, not a definite picture.

**That's what i have:**

[image]

**But this is what i need:**

[image]

Can someone help me with this? :( i'm a little lost on Cycles and materials..

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of you previous question? Also it looks like it is working, the only thing you have to change is your materials.

Comment: Oh, no, on the previous question i was asking about the enviroment Hdri and the reflection, right now i'm only asking about the reflection, because it doesnt work for me, i also tried adding more samples, but is still the same.

Comment: It is obviously reflecting something. The glossy has a very high roughness it looks like . . . could you upload a .blend?

Comment: Ok, give me a second, even though its reflecting something the reflection look pretty blurry :/ give me a sec..

Comment: Ok, here is it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8ot4mtbsw1sw5b/eye.rar?dl=0

Comment: Also check and make sure that you don't have another version of the eye over the one you are working on. That would do it.

Comment: Inside the .rar is the .blend :)

Comment: Still is not working at all :/

Comment: @beavoru You need to change the roughness of your glossy cycles shader. Based on your recent questions, I would recommend you follow some cycles video tutorials, in-order to understand better how it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to turn down the *roughness* on the glossy shader.  Roughness is how much the light scatters away from the perfect specular angle.  It makes for blurrier, less crisp reflections.

Here is a diagram:
[image]
The first three examples on the left are a ray hitting glossy surfaces with varying roughness (left to right no roughness to high roughness), the fourth example is a ray hitting a diffuse surface for comparison.

Comment: The roughness of the glossy shader is 0.017, is pretty low already :/

Comment: Fixed it! i changed the roughness to 0 :D

Comment: Good diagrams! +1

Comment: @VinceScalia Thanks!  I made that diagram a while ago for fun when I was bored, I figured I would use it sooner or later. :D