# Diffuse BSDF texture on cycles doesn't reflect the Hdri in some parts?

Tags: texturing, materials

i was creating a 3D Eye on Blender and i added a Diffuse image texture map, and it reflects an Hdri image, as you can see, the blue part of the eye doesnt reflect this (fig 1.), it's weird since it's only a single geometry with a single texture...It is possible to make it look better, like the image is reflected on all the geometry? (fig 2.)
Does anyone know what to do?
**Or how can i make the Fig 1. looks like exactly the Fig 2.?**

[image]

Comment: Or maybe make it look like exactly like the Fig 2.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reflection of HDRI in Cycles not working?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23251/reflection-of-hdri-in-cycles-not-working)

Comment: isnt the same, thank you anyways, it's almost the same :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reflection is working properly, the problem is that your eye model is not a perfect sphere. the area that is extruded inwards distorts the reflection.

To make it look like a physical eye you will need to create another sphere outside of the one you have and set it as a glass shader. then you will have the reflections you want.